# 6 white, 6 black, 6 ground wires coming out of ceiling

Tags: electrical, ceiling

I'm replacing the fan/light in my sons room with 4 flush mount lights and a fan with no light on it. I removed the old fan and it had 6 2 wire cables with ground so all together there are 6 white wires, 6 black and 6 ground wires. All were bundled with the same color. the room has two light switches. I've hooked up the lights to what I thought was the light switch but it did not work. so I tried all the wires hooked up to the lights and still nothing. does anyone have an idea on what I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hello and welcome to DIY. Please add a picture so we can have a look. Also, take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the ceiling and the switch boxes please?

Comment: That box may be used as junction box too, not only for fan.

Comment: I agree with @user263983, probably being used as junction box.  Just for clarity, are you in the US?

Comment: 6 cables running into and out of it means that this box had better be pretty large!